# How to perform pattern matching with switch for non-constant string value?

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

I'd like to be able to use non-constant string variables as the match target in a switch statement.

I have the code below, but I'm encountering error:

> CS0150: A constant value is expected`at`case expectedValue:

```cs
public bool UseStandardSwitch(string inputValue)
{
    var expectedValue = "SomeValue";

    bool result = default;
    var DoSomething = () => { result = true; };
            
    switch (inputValue)
    {
        case expectedValue:
            DoSomething();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Why use a switch at all, seems like a job for a simple `if`, no?

Comment: nvoigt, The code is not intended to reflect a realistic use case. The goal is to highlight syntax.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No need to introduce a variable (as in your answer) - you can use discard with case guard:

```cs
public bool UseStandardSwitch(string inputValue)
{
    var expectedValue = Console.ReadLine()!;
    Func<bool> DoSomething = () => true;
    
    return inputValue switch
    {
        _ when inputValue.Equals(expectedValue) => DoSomething(),
        _ when inputValue.Equals(expectedValue + "1") => DoSomething(),
        _ => throw new ArgumentException(),
    };
}
```

Comment: On which version of C# has this been introduced?

Comment: @Error404Brainnotfound I believe since C# 8.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the var pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#var-pattern) to accomplish something similar.

Try this:

```cs
public bool UsePatternMatching(string value)
{
    var DoSomething = () => true;

    return value switch
    {
        var str when str.Equals("SomeValue") => DoSomething(),
        _ => throw new ArgumentException(),
    };
}
```

UPDATE: See Stron's post for an better answer.

Comment: This isn't a `switch`, though... it's an if-else disguised as a `switch`. It's also going to require a new variable declaration for every branch of the "switch", which is inefficient.

Comment: May the reader be so lucky as to work on code where variable declarations are a significant contributor to performance overhead :)

Comment: I agree that it's unlikely to be a problem, but it's always good to explain exactly what something is doing behind the scenes to allow readers to make the most appropriate decision for their use-case. Much of the syntactic sugar being added to C# nowadays hides a lot of complexity.

Comment: @IanKemp I know this is an old comment but... a switch statement in C# is effectively syntactic sugar that also compiles to `if` statements. It's amazing how much of C# works that way.