# How to use a switch expression to match a value where it equals another non-constant value

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, equality, c#-11.0, switch-expression

I want to write a method that converts a WPF `System.Windows.FontWeight` property to its equivalent CSS value using C#11. A *switch expression* seems the most appropriate construct. Here's my attempt:

```cs
    string ToCssValue(FontWeight value) => value switch
    {
        FontWeights.Bold => "bold",
        FontWeights.ExtraBold => "bolder",
        FontWeights.Normal => "normal",
        FontWeights.Light => "lighter",
        _ => value.ToOpenTypeWeight().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    };
```

However, I get an error on `FontWeights.Bold`: A constant value of type 'FontWeight' is expected. This is happening because `FontWeights.Bold` is a reference to a specific instance of the `FontWeight` struct. Since `FontWeight` is a Value Type I though the switch expression would be smart enough to know I mean to switch `value` on `FontWeights.Bold` using the default equality, which is 'by value' for value types. However, it appears not.

How can I use a switch expression to match the value of variable with another non-constant value using default equality, or in other words, how do I "switch on `value` where it equals `FontWeights.Bold`"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `_` discard symbol with the `when` keyword followed by an equality expression to match `value` on a non-constant value:

```cs
    string ToCssValue(FontWeight value) => value switch
    {
        _ when value == FontWeights.Bold => "bold",
        _ when value == FontWeights.ExtraBold => "bolder",
        _ when value == FontWeights.Normal => "normal",
        _ when value == FontWeights.Light => "lighter",
        _ => value.ToOpenTypeWeight().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    };
```

Thanks to this Q&A: [How To Perform Pattern Matching With Switch For Non-Constant String Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70215555/660896)

Comment: Why was my answer down-voted? Does it not correctly answer the question? If so, please explain why. If it's because it's an answer to duplicate question, I don't think it's fair to down-vote the answer as well as the question.